# Is it possible to setup Category wise Subsciption?

Tags: plugins, categories

Is there any plugin in Wordpress, which will allow visitor to subscribe my WP Site category wise?
Like when a user will enter his/her mail address to subscriber, (s)he will be asked to select categories on check boxes, so that he will only receive mail alerts for new posts on specific categories he selected.

Comment: There are category specific [feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: There are, but is there any way so that visitor can subscribe to them, so that it will be delivered to his mail. (more specifically subscribing multiple categories at once)

Comment: I don't think there is any Core bundled system that would send email like that. I am not aware of anything like that at least. I would start searching for plugins or gear up to write your own system.

Comment: This is what I concluded after a lot of Googling, thanks for your help anyways, let see if any one else have solution for this